# Writing SQL with timestamps

Tags: mysql, sql

The data

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `transactions` (
  `transactions_ts` timestamp ,
  `user_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `transaction_id` bigint, 
  `item` varchar(200), PRIMARY KEY(`transaction_id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `transactions` (`transactions_ts`, `user_id`, `transaction_id`,`item` ) VALUES
  ('2016-06-18 13:46:51.0', 13811335,1322361417, 'glove'),
  ('2016-06-18 17:29:25.0', 13811335,3729362318, 'hat'), 
  ('2016-06-18 23::07:12.0', 13811335,1322363995,'vase' ),
  ('2016-06-19 07:14:56.0',13811335,7482365143, 'cup'),
  ('2016-06-19 21:59:40.0',13811335,1322369619,'mirror' ),
  ('2016-06-17 12:39:46.0',3378024101,9322351612, 'dress'),
  ('2016-06-17 20:22:17.0',3378024101,9322353031,'vase' ),
  ('2016-06-20 11:29:02.0',3378024101,6928364072,'tie'),
  ('2016-06-20 18:59:48.0',13811335,1322375547, 'mirror');
```

The question: for each user, show the first item that they ordered (first by time). I assume time as a whole timestamp (not time and date separately). 
My attempt

```sql
select 
min(transactions_ts) as first_trans, 
user_id, item
from transactions
group by user_id
order by first_trans;
```

I am sorry that may be it is a simple question, but one person tells me that my query is entirely wrong. And I have got no other means  to test this claim of his

[demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=b774dd9b12b5118e1acfe9bf47db1026)

Comment: Assuming your transaction IDs are incremental, why not just sort by those? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=4d814208e2919c796f8916c7cd06cd14

Comment: Your query is incorrect you are grouping by user id so the item is probably non determinate. You should review  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html particularly the the bits relating to functional dependency.

Comment: @ BenM Too much of an assumption. I was just given the data, I was not told anything about transaction ID.

Comment: 'And I have got no other means to test this claim of his' - how so?

Comment: @BenM You don't have information to assume that

Comment: You are using GROUP BY  in a invalid way which gives non deterministic  ("random") values for item, a [error](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=f20266a81d6d978a6734fd567a8c082f) should happen here.. if the item values are correct for that group record this is purely based on luck as you are playing russian roulette here. .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little bit more complicated than you thought.

To start with: "for each user" would translate to `GROUP BY user_id`, not to `GROUP BY user_id, item`.

But with `GROUP BY user_id`, you'd need an aggregation function saying "the `item` for the minimum `transactions_ts`". MySQL doesn't feature such an aggregation function.

The obvious solution is to make this two steps:

1. Find the first transaction per user
2. Show the items for these transactions

The query:

```
select *
from transactions
where (user_id, transactions_ts) in
(
  select user_id, min(transactions_ts)
  from transactions
  group by user_id
);
```

Another way to word the task is: "Give me the transactions for which no older transaction for the same user exists".

The query:

```
select *
from transactions t
where not exists
(
  select *
  from transactions t2
  where t2.user_id = t.user_id
  and t2.transactions_ts < t.transactions_ts
);
```

Comment: my original query was just group by user_id not item.
I edited  the question, when noticed that it had item in grouping also

Comment: doesn't your first option do exactly the same as  just grouping by user_id only

Comment: yes i got it. thanks. basically, sql has found an item corresponding  to the first transaction by luck.

Comment: I should have grouped by user_id and item to avoid error as @raymon-nijland pointed out, but then the result would be rubbish

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using a subquery to get the first transaction_ts for each user:

```
select user_id, item, transactions_ts
from transactions a
where transactions_ts=(select min(transactions_ts)
                       from transactions b
                       where b.user_id=a.user_id)
```

So your get:

1. In the inner query get the first transaction time for each user
2. In the outer query you get the row that has the time you got at point 1

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MySQL 8.0, window function `ROW_NUMBER()` can be used to adress your use case, as follows:

```
SELECT  transactions_ts, user_id, item
FROM (
    SELECT 
        transactions_ts, 
        user_id, 
        item, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY transactions_ts) rn
    FROM transactions
) x WHERE rn = 1
```

The inner query ranks each record by ascending timestamp, within groups of records having the same `user_id`. The outer query filters in the first transaction of each customer.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0258f3663cbac25fda233dba12003590)**:

```
transactions_ts     |    user_id | item 
:------------------ | ---------: | :----
2016-06-18 13:46:51 |   13811335 | glove
2016-06-17 12:39:46 | 3378024101 | dress
```